# How to cycle trough result set in MySQL 8 while updating the table?

Tags: mysql

I have

- Table A: Known products with product_id and title
- Table B: Scraped product infos with title and URL

My goal now is to find product_id belonging to found products from Table B and save this prouduct_id to Table B.

Finding a product is easy via full text search:

```
SELECT
    mp.SKU
FROM
    my_products mp
WHERE
    MATCH (mp.NAME, mp.QUANTITY) AGAINST ('Some title I search for')
LIMIT 1
```

Now trying to go through all found products:

```
SELECT TITLE, URL,(
                    SELECT
                        mp.SKU
                    FROM
                        my_products mp
                    WHERE
                        MATCH (mp.NAME, mp.QUANTITY) AGAINST (a.TITLE)
                    LIMIT 1
           ) SKU
from amazon_products a
where SKU is null
```

This obviously does not work as I can not reference the outer table. Not mentioning to updating the table and adding the product_id to Table B. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

> The search string must be a string value that is constant during query evaluation.

this why you query will not work and has nothing to do with subquery..

Only  a LIKE or REGEXP expression could handle this.

A stored procedure with dynamic sql could handle this also. but would take a hell of a time to loop thrugh all posibilities

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following update statement.

### Recommended

The `MATCH-AGINST` requires a literal value in the `against` and so a like function may be more ideal here. It may expensive to loop through your resultset and each time querying another table. Below I've used a `LIKE` with wildcard match to achieve this in the update function.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
create table amazon_products (
    product_id int,
    title varchar(20),
    FULLTEXT KEY (title)
);

create table my_products (
    product_id int,
    NAME text,
    QUANTITY varchar(20) default 'some',
    FULLTEXT(NAME, QUANTITY)
);

insert into my_products (product_id,name) values (1,'cardboard'),(2,'tes');

insert into amazon_products values (1,'cars'),(NULL,'test');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select * from amazon_products;
```

| product_id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cars |
|  | test |

---

**Query #2**

```
UPDATE amazon_products a,
       my_products mp
SET a.product_id = mp.product_id
WHERE
    a.title LIKE CONCAT('%',mp.NAME,'%')
    AND
    a.product_id IS NULL;
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #3**

```
select * from amazon_products;
```

| product_id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cars |
| 2 | test |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u1KFGJHJ7eqq5UZQWATheL/0)

### Out of Curiosity, Not recommended

Out of curiosity, I've created a function to achieve this but this may be more expensive.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION fn_get_matching_id(
    TITLE TEXT
)
RETURNS INT NOT DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN
    DECLARE matching_id INT;
    SELECT mp.product_id 
    INTO matching_id
    FROM my_products mp
    WHERE MATCH(mp.NAME,mp.QUANTITY) AGAINST (TITLE IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
    ORDER BY MATCH(mp.NAME,mp.QUANTITY) AGAINST (TITLE IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) DESC
    LIMIT 1;
    RETURN (matching_id);
END
```

**Testing**

> ```
> select * from amazon_products;
> ```

> ```
> product_id | title
> ---------: | :----
>          1 | cars 
>       null | test
> ```

> ```
> select a.*, fn_get_matching_id(a.title)  as suggested_id from amazon_products a;
> ```
>
> ```
> product_id | title | suggested_id
> ---------: | :---- | -----------:
>          1 | cars  |         null
>       null | test  |            2
> ```

> ```
> explain select a.*, fn_get_matching_id(a.title)  as suggested_id from amazon_products a;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra
> -: | :---------- | :---- | :--------- | :--- | :------------ | :--- | :------ | :--- | ---: | -------: | :----
>  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | null       | ALL  | null          | null | null    | null |    2 |   100.00 | null
> ```

> ```
> explain analyze select a.*, fn_get_matching_id(a.title)  as suggested_id from amazon_products a;
> ```
>
> ```
> | EXPLAIN                                                                              |
> | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | -> Table scan on a  (cost=0.45 rows=2) (actual time=0.009..0.017 rows=2 loops=1)<br> |
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE amazon_products a
> SET a.product_id = fn_get_matching_id(a.title)
> WHERE
>     a.product_id IS NULL;
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from amazon_products;
> ```
>
> ```
> product_id | title
> ---------: | :----
>          1 | cars 
>          2 | test
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c2122adac80bedc4b08e8fd261fd0685)*

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Getting the same error as before: "[HY000][1210] Incorrect arguments to AGAINST". The search string must be a literal string using against as I fear the docu shows: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match

Comment: @merlin you are correct. I've updated the answer to use a wildcard match and included a demo fiddle. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you. Using a like statement instead of full text search might be a workaround but does asume that the crawled string contains the exact string I know. Might be OK but the query is significantly slower, now still running since 10m. The products table contains 700.00 products, the crawled table 10.000. I have reduced to about 100.000, still running for now.

Comment: @merlin Out of curiosity I've created a function `fn_get_matching_id` to take advantage of your full text index. I've updated the answer with the code and fiddle to achieve this in addition to some `explain` and `explain analyze` statements to assist in determining whether this may provide an optimal plan of execution for your data that would take advantage of your fulltext index. You may let me know if this works for you also.